# Export order info to .txt file once order is placed

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have researched and tried all possible ideas I could come up with but not having any luck with the below...what am I missing?

The idea is to export a text file once an order has been placed on my Magento store. The text file will then be used for the printer to print the order automatically.

I have created a custom module in Magento which looks at the "sales_order_place_after" (Please advise if this is the wrong event to look at for this) event and executes the Observer.php code.

I have this in config.xml file:

```
    <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <company_printerorder>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>company_printerorder/observer</class>
                    <method>exportOrder</method>
                </company_printerorder>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
```

This is my Observer.php file:

```
class Company_PrinterOrder_Model_Observer 
{

    public function exportOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

    Mage::log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!First line of the Observer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');

    //**** I THINK MY PROBLEM IS HERE
    $event = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getData();
    $observerdata = (get_class_methods($event));
    $observerdata = print_r($observerdata); 




    //Create text file
        // choose correct path
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/magento/printer/orders/';
        if (!is_dir($path)) {

            mkdir($path);
        }

        // create filename
        $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')
            ->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();
        $orderoverall = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $orderNo = $orderoverall->getIncrementId();

        // format 20090403_141048_order_100000007_7.xml
        $filename = date('Ymd_His') . '_order_' . $orderNo . '_' . $orderId . '.txt';

        // create content
        $content = 'content here....' . $observerdata; // create TXT Data here

        // write file to server
        file_put_contents($path . $filename, $content);


    Mage::log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!File has been created!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');

    Mage::log($observerdata);

    Mage::log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Just made a successful Observer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    }
}
```

When I place an order the output is simply just "1". i need to get all the order info exported so that the complete order can print out.

The system log shows:

```
2013-12-11T06:29:18+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 2814
2013-12-11T06:29:18+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 2814
2013-12-11T06:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 2814
2013-12-11T06:29:19+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 2814
2013-12-11T06:29:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!First line of the Observer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2013-12-11T06:29:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!File has been created!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2013-12-11T06:29:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2013-12-11T06:29:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Just made a successful Observer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2013-12-11T06:29:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): SMTPPro is enabled, sending email in Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Template
2013-12-11T06:29:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): Development mode set to send all emails to contact form recipient: email@gmail.com
2013-12-11T06:29:23+00:00 DEBUG (7): ReplyToStoreEmail is enabled, just set Reply-To header: email@gmail.com
2013-12-11T06:29:23+00:00 DEBUG (7): Preparing the Google Apps/Gmail Email transport, email to send with is: email@gmail.com
2013-12-11T06:29:23+00:00 DEBUG (7): Returning transport
2013-12-11T06:29:23+00:00 DEBUG (7): About to send email
2013-12-11T06:29:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): Finished sending email
2013-12-11T06:29:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): template=sales_email_order_template
```

The file gets created; the content only shows:

```
content here....1
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?(still learning...) Any advise would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to export all order data just use this `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getData();`

Comment: Hi, that doesn't work; I think its too big as it just makes the "Place Order" process hang. You have to be more specific with the data you want to get it to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually some more problems with my code; final result looks like this and is now working with exporting the basic data. Still working out the foreach loop of the products as that only exports the last item at this time; but that is out of scope for this question.

Thanks for the assistance gents.

config.xml

```
    <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <company_printerorder>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>company_printerorder/observer</class>
                    <method>exportOrder</method>
                </company_printerorder>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
```

Observer.php

```
class Company_PrinterOrder_Model_Observer 
{

    public function exportOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
    Mage::log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!First line of the Observer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    //Define product items
    $total_items = $order->getTotalItemCount();
    $items = $order->getAllItems();

    if ($items) {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
        $item_info = ' Qty: '.$item['qty_ordered'].' Item:'.$item['name'].' Price: '.$item['price'];
        }
    }



    //CREATE THE TXT FILE
        // choose path
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/magento/printer/orders/';
        if (!is_dir($path)) {

            mkdir($path);
        }

        // format order.txt
        $filename = 'order.txt';

        // create content
        $content =
        'OrderID:' . print_r($order->getIncrementId(), true) . 
        ' AnotherID:' . print_r($order->getId(), true) . 
        ' RealOrderId:' . print_r($order->getRealOrderId(), true) . 
        ' DeliveryMethod:' . print_r($order->getShippingMethod(), true) . 
        ' DeliveryAddress:' . print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getData("street"), true) . ', ' . print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getData("city"), true) . 
        ' Subtotal:' . print_r($order->getSubtotal(), true) . 
        ' DeliveryCharge:' . print_r($order->getShippingAmount(), true) . 
        ' TotalPaid:' . print_r($order->getTotalPaid(), true) . 
        ' TotalDue:' . print_r($order->getTotalDue(), true) . 
        ' CustomerNote:' . print_r($order->getCustomerNote(), true) . 
        ' PhoneNumber:' . print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone(), true) . 
        ' Email:' . print_r($order->getCustomerEmail(), true) . 
        ' CustomerName:' . print_r($order->getCustomerName(), true);


        // write file to server
        file_put_contents($path . $filename, $content);


    Mage::log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Just made a successful Observer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is the line

```
$observerdata = print_r($observerdata);
```

`print_r('blah')` outputs `blah` to stdout and returns `true` on success. This boolean value is casted to string which results in the display of `1` in your script.

Just change this line to

```
$observerdata = print_r($observerdata, true);
```

The second parameter tells `print_r`to return the value and not to print it.

Comment: thanks, I just tried that but then I get a blank result:
 "2013-12-11T09:42:20+00:00 DEBUG (7): " Also Blank in the text file content.

Comment: Did you doublecheck that `$observerdata` contains any data?

Comment: I am trying to get the data out of it... What other method can I use the check if it has data? From what I found with guys doing similar tasks, it seems like the event is the correct one? $observerdata should just get its data from there? Seems like I am just not requesting the data in the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$event = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getData();
```

to

```
$event = $observer->getOrder()->getData();
```

$observer->getOrder() is enough to get order for this event

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below Link :

This link used to export order information into .txt/.csv file format once the order was placed.

https://github.com/vijays91/Magento-Placed-Order-Export